# Outofmemory error tring debug MessageComponentInterface method vars

Tags: laravel-5, socket.io

In my laravel 5.7 app I use MessageComponentInterface for chat app with a class like

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes\Socket;

use App\Classes\Socket\Base\BaseSocket;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class ChatSocket extends BaseSocket
{
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        echo '<pre>New Connection ::'.print_r($conn->resourceId,true).'</pre>';
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv= count($this->clients)-1;
         echo '<pre>onMessage $msg::' . print_r( $msg, true ) ;
//        var_dump($from);
        dump($from);
        die("-1 XXZ000");
        echo '<pre>onMessage $from::' . print_r( $from, true ) ;
        ...
```

The problem is that in onMessage event I want to this message write to db table, but I can not find where to get user_id of user
who sent this message?
I tried to debug outputing values to screen  with

```
echo '<pre>onMessage $from::' . print_r( $from, true ) ;
```

But I got outof memmory error, but in /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini I modified options:

```
max_execution_time = 3330
max_input_time = 240
memory_limit = 4048M
```

and restarted my server, but anyway I got outof memory error

using these metods:

```
//        var_dump($from);
        dump($from);
```

I got endless output in console and I could not catch anything...

How to debug these values ?

**UPDATED # 2**
I try example at
https://laravel.io/forum/01-16-2015-loading-laravels-session-using-ratchet
article, but when I tried to run it with method :

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    $from->session->start();
    $idUser = $from->session->get(Auth::getName());
```

I got error :

```
Undefined property: Ratchet\Server\IoConnection::$session
```

In the mentioned article there was a comment :

> (you must decrypt cookie to get the session id in Laravel 5) :

I search for this I found this

> In web request context cookies are usually automatically encrypted and
>   decrypted by the EncryptCookies middleware.  So easiest option would
>   be just to enable this middleware (and it's enabled by default in
>   Laravel).

and in my app/Http/Kernel.php there is line with EncryptCookies

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
```

but that is web application, but I run console app.
Can the reason of the error that I have to add EncryptCookies to some other group in app/Http/Kernel.php ?
Or why error ?

Also
In file:///etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
I modified

```
memory_limit = 8048M
```

and restarted apache

also I tried to check how many of memory in my script :

```
         echo '<pre>onMessage getNiceFileSize(memory_get_usage()) ::' . print_r( $this->getNiceFileSize(memory_get_usage()) , true ) ;
it shows :19241736 ~18 MiB
```

error message :

```
 Out of memory (allocated 1623195648) (tried to allocate 1600131072 bytes)
```

I tried to calculated and got values 1.51 GiB and 1.49 GiB...

- 1) why memory_get_usage returns such small value 2) Why dumping gets
  1.5 GiB? That is a big value 3) Any ideas how to deal it? 4) Auth::id() returns nothing and as far I understand it would not help,
  as message can be sent by some other logged user, but not currently
  logged...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did yo see this https://laravel.io/forum/01-16-2015-loading-laravels-session-using-ratchet article ?
It has similar example :

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    // start the session when the user send a message 
    // (refreshing it to be sure that we have access to the current state of the session)
    $from->session->start();
    // do what you wants with the session 
    // for example you can test if the user is auth and get his id back like this:
    $idUser = $from->session->get(Auth::getName());
    if (!isset($idUser)) {
        echo "the user is not logged via an http session";
    } else {
        $currentUser = User::find($idUser);
    }
    // or you can save data to the session
    $from->session->put('foo', 'bar');
    // ...
    // and at the end. save the session state to the store
    $from->session->save();
}
```

Comment: Please look at UPDATED # 2 or original topic